# The browser closes by itself while uploading an image

Tags: bug, status-norepro, images, uploader

When I try to upload an image to my question on any Stack Exchange website, my browser simply just, closes all by itself. I usually lose all of my work, and all of my tabs are gone. It's very odd why this happens, and it keeps happening over time.

- Browser: Google Chrome
- OS: Windows 7

[This is a question that is similar to mine,](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280386/data-image-crashes-browser) it's just that his browser freezes and his way of inserting an image is slightly different.

**Can anyone tell me why my browser just closes by itself while uploading an image?**

Comment: What version of Chrome? SE supports only two versions back; If your Chrome is version 68 or older, it's no longer supported and likely to cause problems, not just in the image upload part. In such case, please update your browser and all should work fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How many times has it happened? And is it strictly in Stack Exchange sites? And how much memory does your computer have?

When you upload images, then it's actually not to the Stack Exchange site - it's actually to Imgur, and then the Stack Exchange is inserting that link into the post.

It sounds to me like your browser crashes. When you upload images, I can imagine extra use of memory. Chrome is also known for a high usage of memory. So I would suggest trying using Firefox for a while and seeing if the same error occurs.

If you are on a computer with a limited amount of memory and have a lot of tabs open, then things are bound to fail at some point. :-/

Comment: My computer has lots of memory, but while trying out Firefox, it never happened, and I usually have tons of tabs open. So your method actually worked.

Comment: Maybe your Chrome-installation is corrupt, somehow. There is another browser, that is based on Chrome called [SRWare Iron](https://www.srware.net/en/software_srware_iron.php). I actually use this as my primary browser (don't ask me why). It's like a true copy of Chrome. You could try to install and use that for a while, and see if the error occurs in that as well. You could also try and clear cookies, cache and history, if you want to use Google Chrome.